# ng-disabled not working for multiple inputs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following html form

```
<form name="enviarAutorizacao" id="enviarAutorizacao" novalidate>
  <label class="form-label-gray">autorization</label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-6" ng-model="current.autorizacao" id="autorizacao" ui-mask="" maxlength="20" required>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
    <label class="form-label-gray"> Value </label>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2 form-label-gray">
      <label>$</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-9">
       <input class="form-control" maxlength="16" ng-model="current.valor" required id="valor">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="enviarAutorizacao.$invalid || enviarAutorizacao.$pristine" id="submit-representante-estabelecimento" ng-click="validateAssociate()">click me</button>
  </div> 
</form>
```

I am trying to enable the submit button, only when the 2 inputs are filled, but it is enabling right when I type on the first input (autorizacao).

I tried few alternatives, like change "ng-disabled="enviarAutorizacao.$invalid" to "ng-disabled="!enviarAutorizacao.$valid", but didnt works.

What is wrong with this html ?

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7e3hQIaEQ7n4n3PPJNdC?p=preview. So my guess is that the ui-mask directive is doing something wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried to remove the ui-mask, but still not working. :/

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr. As you see, I literally copied and pasted the code you posted, and I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: its working completely fine . The button is enabled only when user types on both the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `enviarAutorizacao.autorizacao.$invalid` you will know if the "autorizacao" input is Invalid.

```
[form id].[input name].[$valid or $invalid or $dirty...]
```

So your code should be like this:
*I changed the input's name and submit's ng-disabled*

```
<form name="enviarAutorizacao" id="enviarAutorizacao" novalidate>
  <label class="form-label-gray">autorization</label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-6" ng-model="current.autorizacao" id="autorizacao" ui-mask="" maxlength="20" name="autorizacao" required>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
    <label class="form-label-gray"> Value </label>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2 form-label-gray">
      <label>$</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-9">
       <input class="form-control" maxlength="16" ng-model="current.valor" required id="valor" name="valor">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="enviarAutorizacao.autorizacao.$invalid || enviarAutorizacao.valor.$invalid" id="submit-representante-estabelecimento" ng-click="validateAssociate()">click me</button>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using the ids of the actual inputs individually as the arguments to ng-disabled.

Alternatively you could check the validity of current.autorizacao and current.valor and use those.